# How do I create a permalink for different Jquery functions?

Tags: jquery, permalinks

I'm new to Jquery and trying to figure some simple things out. I have several divs that show/hide upon clicking on various links. I would like to be able to have permalinks for each div, so that a user can reload the page and not have to navigate back to the div they were viewing.

Here is the [***jsfiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/Chiisanahime/FFFAj/5/) of what I have so far.

(NOTE: The framework for the fiddle keeps defaulting to Mootools...please reset to JQuery UI.)

My page is structured like this:

```
<div style="width:100%; height:40px; text-align:center;">
<a class="one" href="#">One</a>
<a class="two" href="#">Two</a>
<a class="three" href="#">Three</a>
<a class="four" href="#">Four</a> 
</div>
<div id="one">One</div>
<div id="two">Two</div>
<div id="three">Three</div>
<div id="four">Four</div>
```

with JQuery script that looks like this

```
$('a.one').click(function () {
$("#one").show('slide', {
    direction: 'right'});
$("#two:visible, #three:visible, #four:visible").hide('slide', {
    direction: 'left'});
});

$('a.two').click(function () {
$("#two:hidden").show('slide', {
    direction: 'right'});
$("#one:visible, #three:visible, #four:visible").hide('slide', {
    direction: 'left'});
});

$('a.three').click(function () {
$("#three:hidden").show('slide', {
    direction: 'right'});
$("#one:visible, #two:visible, #four:visible").hide('slide', {
    direction: 'left'});
});

$('a.four').click(function () {
$('#four:hidden').show('slide', {
    direction: 'right'});
$("#one:visible, #two:visible, #three:visible").hide('slide', {
    direction: 'left'});
});
```

Comment: Put the selected tab in the `#hash` of the URL. Then have your `document.ready` function check the hash and simulate a click on the corresponding `a`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not very experienced with JQuery...Can you link me to an example of how that's done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Introduces anchors: `<a class="one" href="#one">One</a>`

Now in JS you can do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    hash = location.hash
    if(hash) {
        name = hash.substr(1)
        $('a.'+name).click();
    }
});
```

This does the following: Once the page loads, it checks the hash (e.g. `#one`) and takes the name out of it ("one"). Now it simulates a [click](http://api.jquery.com/click/) on the element anchor (e.g. `a.one`). Of course, you do this **after** you have bound your events.

*Note*: A lot of jQuery events have a "getter" and "setter" behaviour: If called without a parameter, it will return the value/trigger the event/etc. while passing a value will assign a new value/event function/etc. Consult the linked documentation for details.

Comment: When I add names to the hash, it breaks the sliding transition. See here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Chiisanahime/FFFAj/6/)

Comment: I guess because anchors are meant for naviation and it will jump to a specific section. Maybe you can block it somehow.